# How to fix Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-env' Error in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]all. I'm working on my TS project, however, I noticed that there is an error in the file `tsconfig.json`, which shows below, it really makes feel annoyed, could any one help me how could I solve it? Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: Could you share your entire `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Sure, just wait a minute.